# CKEditor RTL Languages

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am working with a plugin for one of my tools called CKEditor. In the first few phases of the tool, it has been the standard- out of the box use and it has been working fine.

I now need to allow for RTL (Right to Left) languages in the editor for some authors in other countries.

Looking through the configuration, I saw that you were able to enable this on the editor but I am curious if there is any way to auto detect this? A user shouldn't have to specify or enable this manually. At the same time, I need it to support both rtl depending on the users location.

Is there any detection that enables something like this on load as well as when pre-populating the editor with existing content for the user to be able to update? How are RTL editors usually handled with multiple locales?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the new HTML5 attribute: dir="auto"
But for CKEDITOR, we have problem. you should use contentsLangDirection:'auto' in config; but as far as I see, it only works on Chrome Browser.